# Why does $3x^2+y^3+9=-2xy$ cannot be written in explicit form?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, implicit-differentiation, implicit-function

For this equation

$$3x^2 + y^3 + 9 = -2xy,$$

I checked on wolfram alpha and it doesn't seem to have an explicit form where $y$ is isolated and equals a function of $x$'s only.

The problem is that I don't understand why it can't be written explicitly, as the graph of the relation is a [non injective] function : it doesn't have more than one value of $y$ for each value of $x$.

So I should be able to write it as any normal function where $y = f(x)$ and its derivative with respect to $x$ should be expressed with only $x$'s instead of $x$'s and $y$'s - its derivative is : $\frac{-2(3x+y)}{3y^2+2x}$.

Please illuminate me, i'm really clueless.

Comment: Technically, you can write it as $y^3+(2x)y+(3x^2+9)=0$ and apply the general solution to the cubic equation to get $y$ in terms of $x$. But you might get three different real $y$ for some $x$.

Comment: Wolfram alpha has an explicit form...?

Comment: Turns out, the discriminant is always negative, so there is always one real root.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to wolfram alpha, there does exist a real explicit form:

[image]

Comment: Oh wut, damn my bad, I overlooked it.